# How to the get value of next text input?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing my project in IE 7 and I want to know how to get the value of the text input whenever I click the label before it .

here's my DOM:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
 <label id="lbl_name">Name:</label>
</td>
<td>
 <input type="text" id="name" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried using the nextSibling but I'm getting the a blank value .

```
document.getElementById('lbl_name').attachEvent('onclick', function () {
 alert(document.activeElement.nextSibling.nodeValue);
});
```

Any help please? If you can share your code in a non-jquery way. Thanks

Comment: That label is useless. It doesn't have any descendants that are controls or a for attribute.

Comment: First get your HTML correct: use the "for" attribute on the label like this: <label for="name">Name:</label>. The for attribute should point to the id of the field it belongs to. Then use the method that @Quentin describes here below.

Comment: `label` uses the input's `id` to connect the two. Your `label` could just as easily be a `div` or `span`. However, to answer your question, use the parent `td`'s nextSibling child `input`.

Comment: `attachEvent` is non-standard code for ancient versions of IE. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: "ancient" LOL I remember IE before they had version numbers.

Comment: [Don't](http://purecss.io/forms/) use [tables](http://www.sitepoint.com/style-web-forms-css/) for [layout](http://designshack.net/articles/10-css-form-examples/).

Comment: @Quentin attachEvent is working here in IE 7

Comment: @itagomo: Like he said.  Ancient.  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified @Kenneth's answer, and here's what made it working:

```
document.getElementById('lbl_name').attachEvent('onclick', function () { alert(document.activeElement.nextSibling.children[0].value);
});
```

`document.activeElement` is the 'label' that I clicked on, `nextSibling` will be the `<td>` tag that holds the `<input>` element and `children[0]` is the `<input type="text">`. Adding `.value` on it will return the text inside it.

thanks guys for all your inputs =D

Answer (score 4):

The input is not a sibling of the label. To use that approach, you would need to:

1. get the parent node (the td)
2. get the next sibling of that node
3. get the first input descendant of that node

However, the label is useless at the moment as it isn't associated with the input at all. If you fix your markup:

```
<label id="lbl_name" for="name">Name:</label>
```

You can:

```
document.getElementById( this.getAttribute('for') ).value
```

Comment: For reference, `this.htmlFor` should return the same value as  `this.getAttribute('for')`.

Comment: here's what I did after adding for="name" on the label: document.getElementById('lbl_name').attachEvent('onclick', function () {
  alert(document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('for')).value);
});

but getting error 'Objectdoesn't support this property or method

Comment: I don't have a copy of IE handy, so I just get *Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLabelElement> has no method 'attachEvent'*, but if I use standard code then [it works fine](http://jsbin.com/uvUbOpu/1/).

Comment: yes, your code runs in different browsers but I need to make it work in IE 7 (company reasons). It's really challenging to do this on classic IE versions .

Comment: looks like `'this.getAttribute('for')'` is not for IE 7 and below.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the field is not a sibling.

You'd have to go up to the parent, to the sibling and then the first child:

```
document.activeElement.parentNode.nextSibling.children[0];
```

That is, if you have no text nodes in between

Comment: I did it by removing 'parentNode' . code: document.getElementById('lbl_name').attachEvent('onclick', function () {
        alert(document.activeElement.nextSibling.children[0].value);
  });

Comment: i got nothing with document.activeElement.parentNode.nextSibling.children[0].value